# Ардуино использует только C/C++ или есть что то для Js? Ну например NodeBots?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, arduino

Ардуино использует только C/C++ или есть что то для Js? Ну например NodeBots?

Comment: Arduino работает с любым языком программирования, который может компилироваться (или имеет интерпретатор) под AVR процессоры. Просто родная среда разработки использует С-язык.

Answer (score 1):

Например, плата [Iskra JS](http://amperka.ru/product/iskra-js) программируется на JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Да, есть такие фреймворки - вот например парочка из них

1. [Johnny-Five](http://johnny-five.io/)
2. [Cylon.js](https://cylonjs.com/)
3. [Node-Red](https://nodered.org/)

Все эти проекты будут работать с arduino.

Кроме того есть проект [Espruino](https://www.espruino.com/) - это платка на которую разработчики изначально заточили написание кода на JS